# Find an e-mail in the system and remove, that appears in logs

Tags: server, email

I have a problem on my ubuntu server. Some guy has added his e-mail somewhere and my server tries to send him e-mails. I have searched using grep:

```
/var/log # grep -n "guys_name@gmail.com" *
```

And got this:

```
syslog.1:6538:Aug 21 03:39:54 lovecakes postfix/smtp[24625]: A49A315A951: to=<guys_name@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.165.27]:25, delay=2.9, delays=1.2/0/0.46/1.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1408585194 wr8si36296852lbc.79 - gsmtp)
syslog.1:6864:Aug 21 04:32:18 lovecakes postfix/smtp[24949]: A04A215A951: to=<guys_name@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4010:c08::1a]:25, delay=12, delays=10/0.01/0.4/1.6, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1408588338 t1si36397231laj.89 - gsmtp)
syslog.1:6990:Aug 21 04:50:56 lovecakes postfix/smtp[25071]: 0D54315A951: to=<guys_name@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4010:c08::1b]:25, delay=3.1, delays=1.4/0/0.34/1.3, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4010:c08::1b] said: 550-5.7.1 [2a01:4f8:d15:1fc4::2      12] Our system has detected that this 550-5.7.1 message is likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent 550-5.7.1 to Gmail, this message has been blocked. Please visit 550-5.7.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188131 for 550 5.7.1 more information. c2si36483814lac.0 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

My aliases is clean:

```
# vim /etc/aliases
```

And I don't know where to find his entry and remove it, so that my server stops trying to send him e-mails.

Comment: It's probably not "in your system" anywhere really. Just delete the message from the postfix queue. It looks like you probably have an open relay on your server, and some spam bot found it and is trying to relay mail through your host.

Comment: No. I don't have open relay definetely. I found him using grep already. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
root@myserver /home # grep -r 'guys_name' /etc
Binary file /etc/postfix/transport.db matches
Binary file /etc/postfix/recipient_bcc.db matches
```

Found him there.